# How to insert complex stucture in a collection in mongoDB (considering indexes)

Tags: mongodb

I have a document (example):

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("51a60a6fff48ea884a04d3eb"),
  "Code" : "07501013118018",
  "Description" : "NECTAR JUMEX",
  "State" : 1,
  "Kind" : "Drink",
  "Unit" : "U"
  "Stock": [{'Store': 1, 'Stock': 8}, {'Store': 2, 'Stock': 4}, {'Store': 3, 'Stock': 3}],
  "Supplier": [{'Code': '001'}, {'Code': '008'}, {'Code': '012'}]
}
```

This structure have an Unique Index in field "Code", but the Sub-field "Store" also must be an index (same situation with "Supplier"):

1. When I want to Update, I just find the record by field "Code" and change data
2. When I want to Insert, find the document by field "Code", if is found, update, if not, insert.

If I want to insert a document with an existing "Code", but with an "Store" not existing, I need to add this ¿how can I do that? (same situation with "Supplier")

Thankful in advance

Answer (score 0):

You want to insert a document with an existing "Code", but with a "Store" not existing? Just insert it:

```
> db.collection.insert({Code: "1"})
```

But maybe I didn't understand your question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer... my question: was how can I insert/update/Delete "Stock" field? (more Stores or update Stock in stores for example).